# Using Meteor 1.3 and Angular 1.5, how do you use TemplateUrl to access an HTML in imports?

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I can define a directive or component that has a TemplateUrl in the client directory, but when I try to pull it access it from an imports directory, it can't find it.  A little debugging showed that the file was not in the angular template cache, which makes sense as imports should be lazy loaded.  I would like to keep all the component files in the same directory (in imports), so I do a access an HTML file from an imports directory?

Answer (score 1):

Angular only run on client and the html file required in templateUrl only available on client when you import them with import syntax. Best practice if you want to keep your component files together is

1. Create a new `index.js` in your component folder
2. In the index file, Import your js, html file and all related files with import "`./file.extension`"
3. Import your index.js from client folder with "`/Imports/startup/client/urcomponent/`"
4. The Template file shall available thr `/Imports/startup/client/urcomponent/`

Cheer